# In c++, Netbeans IDE throws "Unable to resolve identifier String"

Tags: c++, function, declaration

I am getting a couple of errors that I am confused about

There is this function declaration that Netbeans IDE keeps throwing an error about

```
    string  GetValue(const std::string& key);
```

The error I am getting is-

> Unable to resolve identifier String

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Call it `std::string`.

Comment: specify the namespace on your return value

Comment: using namespace std or std::string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've remembered to include the header:

```
#include <string>
```

Then you can then use as indicated above

```
std::string GetValue(const std::string& key);
```

or

```
using namespace std;
string GetValue(const string& key);
```

Comment: As Kevin implies below, the using namespace is normally fine in a CPP file, but not in a header file, because it forces everyone who uses your header to use "using namespace", thereby polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Yes, it's to the point IMO that I would be intrigued to know if there's a compiler out there smart enough to throw an error if it sees a `using namespace` in a `.h` file.  I'd turn on that compiler option all the time.  May or may not exist though.

Answer (score 0):

#include <...>
#include <...>

**using namespace std;**

...

string GetValue(const string& key);

...

That's all

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but I would not recommend polluting your namespace by using 
`using namespace std;` instead, just rename all of the calls that use a `string` with `std::string`.

This is much more concise and helps with auto-completion.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
std::string GetValue(const std::string& key);
```

Best if you added the namespace in the header file so you don't have to qualify the std namespace everywhere in your code.

Comment: I'm all for adding whatever namespaces you want in your .cpp files (and will encourage it in most cases), but I'm also dead-set against polluting your header files with them.  I don't want a random include that I used, be including something else, that includes something else, that THEN has `using namespace std` which then possibly re-defines the meanings of *many* things in my code.  Just say no.

Comment: I presume the -1 is for suggesting adding "using namespace" in the header and not for the correct prototype (a bit harsh).  I agree that this is a bad idea - see my comment above.

Comment: "Best"? That's the first I've heard of that, in fact, isn't it the opposite?